# Q: Python3 - If Statements for changing list lengths

Tags: list, python-3.x, if-statement, indexing

I am attempting to analyze data sets as lists of differing lengths. I am calling lines (rows) of my data set one by one to be analyzed by my function. I want the function to still be run properly regardless of the length of the list.

My Code:

```
f = open('DataSet.txt')
for line in iter(f):

remove_blanks = ['']
entries = line.split()
''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
trash = (entries[0], entries[1])
time = int(entries[2])
column = [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]


def myFun():
    print(entries)
    print_string = ''
    if column[0] == 100:
        if column[1] >= 250 and column[2] == 300:
            if len(column) >= 9:
                digit = [chr(x) for x in column[4:9]]
                print_string = ('code: ' + ''.join(str(digit[l]) for l in range(5)) + ' ')
            if len(column) >= 13:
                optional_digit = [chr(d) for d in column[9:13]]
                for m in range(0, 4):
                    print_string += 'Optional Field: ' + optional_digit[m] + ''
            else:
                print_string += 'No Optional Field '
        pass
    pass
    print(print_string)
    print('')


myFun()

f.close()
```

What is happening is if the length of a line of my data is not long enough (i.e. the list ends at `column[6]`), I get the error:

```
line 17, in function
    print('Code: ' + digit[l])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want it to still print `Code: #number #number #number #number` and leave any non-existent columns as blanks when it is printed so that one line may print as `Code: ABC9` and the next print as `Code: AB` if there are differing list lengths.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just make sure you're not looping over a list longer than available:

```
print_string = 'code: ' + ''.join(str(digit[l]) for l in range(min(5, len(digit)))) + ' '
```

or better:

```
print_string = "code {} ".format("".join(str(dig) for dig in digit[:5]))
```

Although I have a feeling you're over-complicating this.

Comment: Thank you! I am just now learning to program so I am sure this is overcomplicated but it seems that your solution worked. I just had to change the len(column) condition for the if statement and put your code in. Thanks